# Changing clicked imageview's background in a listview

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter

There is a custom adapter for extended ListFragment.Each row of a list is ImageView on the left side and TextView on the right side.On clicking of an image, the ImageView should change its background to different image. I've implemented it this way:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
...
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // context.firstViewItem = position;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,
                    null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.likeBtn = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.likeBtn);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
            viewHolder.likeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                 view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.abc_btn_rating_star_on_mtrl_alpha);

                }
            });
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

But the problem is, not only this ImageView's background change but every imageview in a third or fourth row of listview change. How can I change only clicked imageview's background?

Answer (score 0):

add some code like this in your **MainActivity**:

```
            viewHolder.likeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {

        if(position==R.id.IMAGE_1){
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_1);
        }
    else if(position==R.id.IMAGE_2){
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_2);
    }
     }
});
```

Here **R.id.IMAGE_1** is your ImageView id in xml file.

Comment: care to elaborate on R.id.IMAGE_1?

Comment: it's your image view id, in a xml file

Answer (score 0):

There may be problem with respect to TAG of row element so prefer to use viewholder instance everytime

> Because when scrolling occurs, recycler recycles the first row
>   elements and display new row. So, in scrolling scenario, the
>   onClickListener may be dispatched to newly arranged row at specific
>   index.

To avoid this, we should use tag and  view holder

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
...
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // context.firstViewItem = position;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,
                    null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.likeBtn = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.likeBtn);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
            viewHolder.likeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                 viewHolder.likeBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.abc_btn_rating_star_on_mtrl_alpha);   
// this should solve your problem
                }
            });
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```